How does linux report SNAT port exhaustion
I would like to monitor a router for potential SNAT port exhaustion. I'm fully aware of how unlikely this is to happen. I would still like to know how I could detect this on my running system. Does Linux report this error anywhere?

What is "NAT Port exhaustion"? There are 65,535 ports available for outgoing connections.

I want to know what happens if I have more than 65535 outgoing connections (per destination/destination port, I guess)

Please edit your post to specify this more promimently; it will help avoid requests for clarification.

To answer the actual question: Yes, Linux does report the error "too many open files" to the last client trying to get out.


I would like to monitor a router for potential SNAT port exhaustion. Does Linux report this error anywhere?

The same source port can be used by different source IP addresses multiple times.
For instance if there are 5 hosts behind a NAT router that means a maximum of 5 x 65535 potential source ports.
The reason for that is how NAT works, NAT does not only pay attention to the source port, but also (first) to the source address and only then to the source port.
This would be an issue only if you had 65535 outgoing connections from a single host (IP).

I want to know what happens if I have more than 65535 outgoing connections

It's extremely unlikely to have that many outbound connections from single a host (that is, single IP).
But if that ever happens then that host is likely an extreme example of a zombie system

means a maximum of 5 x 65535 DIFFERENT potential source ports.

@symcbean not numerically different but same 65535 ports except reused by different IP's which is fine.

I'm fully aware of how unlikely this is to happen. I would still like to know how I could detect this on my running system

@Philippe I think you would experience network failures because either the packets would be directed toward wrong local service or otherwise they would be dropped entirely without forwarding them to any local service at all. (but I have no reference or docs for this)
